# Function ending before all results are returned

Tags: sql-server, xml, function, dotnetnuke

I’m using this function which allows me to query list values held in a large XML table in MS SQL 2005.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.KB_XMod_ExtractListFieldValue 
( 
@InstanceData ntext, 
@FieldName nvarchar(80) 
) 
RETURNS nvarchar(255) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @Return nvarchar(255) 
DECLARE @Start int 
DECLARE @End int 
DECLARE @FieldValueLength int 
DECLARE @FieldNameLength int 

SELECT @Return=dbo.KB_XMod_ExtractFieldValue(@InstanceData,@FieldName)     
SELECT @Start = CHARINDEX('<value>', @Return) 
SELECT @FieldNameLength = LEN('<value>') 
SELECT @End = CHARINDEX('</value>', @Return) 
SELECT @FieldValueLength = (@End - (@Start + @FieldNameLength)) 


IF @FieldValueLength > 0 
SELECT @Return = SUBSTRING(@Return, @Start + @FieldNameLength, @FieldValueLength) 
ELSE 
SELECT @Return = '' 

RETURN @Return 

END
```

This allows me to construct a query such as:

```
SELECT dbo.KB_XMod_ExtractFieldValue(InstanceData,'Name')
FROM KB_XMod_Modules 
WHERE FormID=18
```

The problem is the function only returns the first set in any record. So if an XML record looks like this...

```
<Name>
            <items>
              <item>
                <label>Jimmy</label>
                <value>960</value>
              </item>
              <item>
                <label>John</label>
                <value>938</value>
              </item>
              <item>
                <label>Robert</label>
                <value>989</value>
              </item>
    </items>
</Name>
```

I only get the first item back – ie `<label>Jimmy</label><value>960</value>`. 
Functions are still a mystery to me but it appears my one is stopping at the first value and not looping through the rest. How can I get it to return all of the items?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You'd normally parse XML with XPath inside SQL Server like this

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<Name>
            <items>
              <item>
                <label>Jimmy</label>
                <value>960</value>
              </item>
              <item>
                <label>John</label>
                <value>938</value>
              </item>
              <item>
                <label>Robert</label>
                <value>989</value>
              </item>
    </items>
</Name>'

SELECT
   x.item.value('label[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
   x.item.value('value[1]', 'int')
FROM
   @xml.nodes('/Name/items/item') x(item)
```

In this case, I'd try something like this which assumes you get xml from `KB_XMod_ExtractFieldValue`

```
DECLARE @xml xml;

SELECT @xml = dbo.KB_XMod_ExtractFieldValue(InstanceData,'Name')
FROM KB_XMod_Modules 
WHERE FormID=18;

SELECT
   x.item.value('label[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
   x.item.value('value[1]', 'int')
FROM
   @xml.nodes('/Name/items/item') x(item);
```

However, you have bigger problems: You are trying to get table-like data back using a scalar function that truncates the xml data

- if you want a table back, you need to use RETURNS TABLE. See [CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)
- you have @Return as nvarchar(255) which will truncate anyway

Note: this is a function not a stored procedure which starts `CREATE PROCEDURE`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my Function / SP slip. I've now edited the original post.

Comment: @Willb: and what about the rest of my answer please...?

Comment: @gbn Thanks for your thoughts. I was hoping it would be as simple as getting the original function to loop but as I said I'm way out of my comfort zone on this. With that in mind, I need to understand you're approach before I can set up a test.

Comment: @Willb: SQL is set based, not loop based, so this approach works to get the data. How did you want it back? As a CSV or scalar or you expected a table with nvarchar(255) columns?

Comment: @gbn I'm using the query to populate a multi-select list box. The data (and results) are all stored as text.

Comment: @Willb: in which case, you need `RETURNS @items TABLE (Item nvarchar(255)` under CREATE FUNCTION, "Transact-SQL Multistatement Table-valued Function Syntax"